# Cycle css div left with an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, html, iteration

This code goes direct to the last position of the array, what I want is to iterate or cycle through them all and at the last position go to the first of the array. I'm tried something else but it gave me an error parsing left in firefox. This is the code fiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jobson111/m6w6K/).

Body:

```
 <div id="placeDiv">ok</div>
 <script>
    var times = ["2px","2000px","200px","12px","20px","200px","2000px"];
    var move=times;             
    var i=0;
    if(i == move.length-1) 
    {i=0;}
    else
    {i=i+1;};
    document.getElementById("placeDiv").style.left=move[i];
 </script>
```

Css:

```
<style>#placeDiv{position:absolute;top:0px;width:100px;height:100px;background-color:purple}</style>
```

This code does not work:

```
    var times = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 30000; i++) {
        times.push("\""+i+"px\"");
 }   var move=times;             
         if(i == move.length-1) 
     {i=0;}
     else
     {i=i+1;};
document.getElementById("placeDiv").style.left=move[i];
```

With the code above I get a this error in firefox:
Error in parsing value for 'left'.  Declaration dropped.

Comment: What you are trying to get with this? It runs only once.. so what you do with that array of values.. Should you use some kind of timer?

Comment: Animate, maybe a for loop is necessary but even so I can't get results.

Comment: try timing event http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use `setTimeout` here. For example:

```
var times = ["2px", "20px", "30px", "12px", "20px", "200px", "20px"],
    move = 0,
    div = document.getElementById("placeDiv");

setTimeout(function next() {
    div.style.left = times[move++ % times.length];
    setTimeout(next, 1000)
}, 1000);
```

To cycle an array values it's very useful to use `%` operator.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m6w6K/1/

Or with `setInterval`:

```
function makeMove() {
    div.style.left = times[move++ % times.length];
}

setInterval(makeMove, 1000);
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m6w6K/4/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function sleep(millis, callback) {
    setTimeout(function()
            { callback(); }
    , millis);
}

var times = ["2px","20px","20px","12px","20px","2000px","20px"];
var move=times;     
var i=0;

(function foobar_cont(){
        if(i == move.length-1) {i=0;}
        else {i=i+1;};
        document.getElementById("placeDiv").style.left=move[i];
        sleep(1000, foobar_cont);
})();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m6w6K/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I've taken dfsq's original answer, and added some spice to it:

```
$(div).animate({left: times[move++ % times.length]}, 500);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m6w6K/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

There was a syntax error in your codes ... [Link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/8LeQ7/) . It works very well for me but .. the "times" or transition is not visible to the user .. cause its to fast. :)

```
 <div id="placeDiv">ok</div>
 <script>
    var times = ["2px","2000px","200px","12px","20px","200px","2000px"];
    var move=times;             
    var i=0;
    if(i == move.length-1) 
    {i=0;}
    else
    {i=i+1;}
    document.getElementById("placeDiv").style.left=move[i];
 </script>
```

Comment: How fast? And if can do HD with a couple of pixels divs? In other words a 2d for loop with the row of 768 divs and columns of 1024 divs.